# react I want to add a state to the array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to change the state in the array
When the onClickEdit process is called, we want to change the id and the value of the isEdit in the array.
I've written the code described below, but I get an error.

**error**
The type'{id: number; isEdit: true;}' cannot be assigned to the type'[{id: number; save: {isEdit: boolean; name: string;};}]'.
Object literals can only specify known properties. 'id' does not exist in type'[{id: number; save: {isEdit: boolean; name: string;};}]'. ts (2322)

```
interface ISavedSearch {
  savedSearch: [{ id: number; save: { isEdit: boolean; name: string } }];
}

export const SaveListCard: FunctionComponent<Props> = () => {

  const onClickEdit = (id: number) => {
    setState({ ...state, savedSearch: { id: id, isEdit: true } });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say without seeing more of your code, but when you call `setState({ ...state, savedSearch: { id: id, isEdit: true } });` you are not setting `savedSearch` as an array enforced by `ISavedSearch`.

Try changing that line to:

```
setState({
  ...state,
  savedSearch: [{
    id,
    save: {
      isEdit: true,
      name: 'foo'
    }
  }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

type'`{id: number; isEdit: true;}`' is not the same as type'`[{id: number; save: {isEdit: boolean; name: string;};}]`'

try to make an interface and you will see the difference,
you're missing the 'save' property